# Some questions from a .NET developer about running Java programs in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a C# developer and have a few questions about using Eclipse.

1. How do I see the list of members of a class like the **Object Browser** shows in Visual Studio?
2. How do I see the source code of a class in Java like Reflector or IL Spy decompile IL into C# or VB or IL itself? When I held down the `Ctrl` key on the keyboard and clicked a framework provided class such as `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`, it showed me what I think is byte code for the class. The page that came up looks like the picture below:

[image]

That may look like Java source code but upon scrolling down further, it looks like it is byte code.

[image]

A few days ago, I downloaded the [CFR decompiler](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/). It was a RAR file. I downloaded it alright but then didn't know what to do with it or how to use it. Double-clicking that RAR file did nothing.

3. Is there a way to generate stubs for methods of a base class that I would like to override in a derived class? In Visual Studio, as soon as you typed `override`, Visual Studio Intellisense would bring up a list of overridable methods from the base classes. Is there something similar in Eclipse?

Comment: With almost 7000 points, you should know by now that you should stick to one question per question on stack overflow. I suggest that you edit this question so it only asks one question, and then post two other questions with your other two questions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I will keep that in mind for future questions. Thank you. For this one, I think Mickael has provided an answer to all the three questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can show the `Outline`: `Window > Show View... > Outline`. If you don't want to have it always visible, you can also show the "Quick Outline" as a pop-up with `Ctrl+o`
2. Usually, you'll deal with open-source libraries in the Java world, so you don't have to decompile stuff. You can configure "Source attachments" for your project to reference the source, and Eclipse will be able to show it rather than this basic class viewer. See http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-source-attachment.htm . Note that for Maven-based projects, this can usually happen automatically (Maven support will fetch and associate source by itself)
3. Just hit `Ctrl+Space` in your class body, without anything before it, and it will suggest methods to override and create the method stub.

Comment: Thank you very much. From where do I get the source code of the `HttpServlet` class? I see the source here (http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/) but do not know which version I should be getting. The byte code shown above indicates that the class files I have are for v1.7 but there is no such version on that page that lists the source code.

Comment: Expand the `Libraries` node in `Project Explorer`, and you'll see the jar, whose name usually contains the version. A solution to find it easily is also to enable the `Link with editor` button on your Project Explorer so it should show you which file is currently open (HttpServlet.class) and from which jar it's loaded. From the jar, you get the name, the version, and you can find which file to download and associate it.

Comment: Thanks very much. :-)